# Problem installing Umbraco with Microsoft Web Platform Installer 

Tags: installation, umbraco, platform

I've been trying to install Umbraco using the Microsoft Web Platform Installer. I'm not sure what credentials to enter for "Database Administrator" and "Database Administrator Password". I've tried the default "sa" as "Database Administrator, and for every password i use i get the error message: "Login failed for sa". Please what really should I do? Thanks a lot for the help.

Edit: Okay after some googling I got help on the Database Administrator issue here:  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/29/sql-server-change-password-of-sa-login-using-management-studio.

But when I launch Umbraco from the WPI window, I get redirected to this url: "http://localhost/install/default.aspx?redir=true&url=/myumbraco "(my app name being MyUmbraco), and get a "404 Not Found Error". 
What should I do now? Please help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem but found a solution here: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/how-to-install-umbraco-on-windows-server-2008

"When using the Web PI be certain to leave the Application Name field blank, otherwise the installer will place Umbraco into a sub folder under a web root, which is not supported."

An easy thing to miss.

Comment: Why oh why would they not support Virtual Directories. It would seem like such an obvious thing to want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

> Login to Umbraco
>   ‘http://localhost/website_name/umbraco’
>   and enter Username and Password.
>   Username is always ‘umbraco’ as
>   default. Password is what you chose in
>   the configuration when you were asked
>   to change it.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Umbraco/Installation/Installing_Umbraco_on_Windows_XP_Professional

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET 3.5 , ensure you have the 3.5 Web.config file downloaded. This is a separate download from Codeplex. I do not know which version the platform installer uses.